не получается у бота зафиксировать сообщение от другого бота (telebot)
мой бот должен улавливать сообщения чужих ботов, чтобы проверять их на содержание ссылок для дальнейшей обработки таких сообщений, но проблема в том что видимо из за самой устройства ботов в тг или самой библиотеке telebot, другие боты не могут видеть сообщения отправленные другими ботами(даже со всеми правами). Единственный выход который я пока нашел - запоминать айди последнего и нового сообщения, но это добавляет множества проблем, тк придется работать с базой данных, где должно запоминаться айди группы в которой есть бот, и для каждой группы отдельно запоминать айди последнего и нового сообщения. короче говоря, я не смогу такое написать даже если захочу. Поэтому может кто знает, как просто в тупую фиксировать сообщения отправленное другим ботом, чтобы без всяких айди сходу проверить его на содержание ссылок?
